# I can't go to design mode in NetBeans (jframe)

Tags: swing, netbeans, jframe

I am building a GUI using swing Jframe. I am using netbeans, because it has this nice interface that allows you to create your GUI just by clicking. I once saved just the Java file of the Interface. Now I want to use this file again and it works fine, when I just add this file to a package inside a project. But I cant go to the design view anymore, the option is not available.

Does anyone know how to enable the design view?

Looking at it there is no .form file. Any idea how to compile this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can recreate the *.form* file from the class. Please see here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormGeneratingFormFile

If you move / copy your class you also have to copy the form file since it's not recreated.